# how to use select() and map() in spark - scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-migration

Im writing a code for data migration from mysql to cassandra using spark. I m trying to generalize it so that given a conf file it can migrate any table. Here im stuck at 2 places:

1. `val dataframe2 = dataframe.select("a","b","c","d","e","f")`
   After Loading the table from mysql i wish to select only a few columns, i have the names of these columns as a list. How can it be used here?
2. `val RDDtuple = dataframe2.map(r => (r.getAs(0), r.getAs(1), r.getAs(2), r.getAs(3), r.getAs(4), r.getAs(5)))`
   Here again every table may have a different number of columns, so how can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue

Comment: in the code that i have written im explicitly specifying the column names (which i dont want) in select(), correct me if im wrong, but select() does not take an array or list as argument. Also, when the number of columns are not fixed, how would the map() change?

Comment: of course it does, select can take a repeated argument as a parameter. as for your second query you can convert your row into a string with an implicit function and split on this to create an array and in case you want to convert it into a tuple, you'll need to process that afterwards

Comment: Really sorry for the trouble, but im still not able to do this: 'val abc:List[String] = List("id","code","name","parent_id","created","modified")
val y = channel.select(abc)' . Can u give an example

Comment: I've already answer questions like this before. try to search about what repeated parameters are in scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use variable number of columns in `select()`, your list of columns can be converted like this:

`val columns = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
val dfSelectedCols = dataFrame.select(columns.head, columns.tail :_*)`

Explanation: the first param in [`DataFrame`'s `select(String, String...)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) is mandatory, so use `columns.head`. The remaining part of the list need to be converted to varargs using `columns.tail :_*`.

2. It's not very clear from your example, but I suppose that `x` is a `RDD[Row]` and that you are trying to convert into a `RDD` of `Tuple`s, right ? Please give more details and also use meaningful variable names. `x`, `y` or `z` are bad choices, especially if there is no explicit typing.

Comment: Thanx a lot, this works. As far as (2) is concerned, x is a 'dataframe' and i wish to convert it to 'RDD' of Tuples. Sorry abt the names, i ll keep that in mind next time